# how to get input file name in hadoop cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

In map-reduce I would extract the input file name as following

```
public void map(WritableComparable<Text> key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

      FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
      String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
      System.out.println("File name "+filename);
      System.out.println("Directory and File name"+fileSplit.getPath().toString());

    process(key,value);

}
```

How can I do the similar with cascading

```
Pipe assembly = new Pipe(SomeFlowFactory.class.getSimpleName());
Function<Object> parseFunc = new SomeParseFunction();
assembly = new Each(assembly, new Fields(LINE), parseFunc);
...

public class SomeParseFunction extends BaseOperation<Object> implements Function<Object> {
...

 @Override
    public void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess, FunctionCall<Object> functionCall) {

how can I get the input file name here ???    
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Cascading but I think it should be sufficient to access the context instance, using functionCall.getContext(), to obtain the filename you can use:

```
String filename= ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
```

However, it seems that cascading use the old API, if the above doesn't work you must try with:

```
Object name = flowProcess.getProperty( "map.input.file" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank Engineiro for sharing the answer. However, when invoking hfp.getReporter().getInputSplit() method, I got MultiInputSplit type which can't be casted into FileSplit type directly in cascading 2.5.3. After diving into the related cascading APIs, I found a way and retrieved input file names successfully. Therefore, I would like to share this to supplement Engineiro's answer. Please see the following code.

```
HadoopFlowProcess hfp = (HadoopFlowProcess) flowProcess;
MultiInputSplit mis = (MultiInputSplit) hfp.getReporter().getInputSplit();
FileSplit fs = (FileSplit) mis.getWrappedInputSplit();
String fileName = fs.getPath().getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by getting the reporter within the buffer class, from the provided flowprocess argument in the buffer operate call.

```
HadoopFlowProcess hfp = (HadoopFlowProcess) flowprocess; 

FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)hfp.getReporter().getInputSplit();
.
.//the rest of your code
.
```